# Get vim to pass the current file path to my shell

Tags: shell, powershell, vim

I already have this in my vimrc:

```
set shell=powershell
set shellcmdflag=-command
```

Now I want to pass powershell the path of the current file so it can run it. I tried this:

```
nnoremap <C-q> :! expand('%:p')<cr>
```

And here is what I see in powershell:

```
powershell -command " expand('\\path\to\my\file....
```

Obviously this doesn't work because I've that darn **expand()** in there. How can I pass just the full path of the current file to my shell?

Also, before anyone says something I have my own mapping I use for visual block which is why I'm re-mapping `<C-q>`

Comment: If the `expand(` makes it through literally and the `%` gets expanded (despite vim clearly not running the `expand` function)... that leads you to your solution don't you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The special characters like `%` (`:help cmdline-special`) are automatically expanded by Vim "at places where a file name can be used" (to quote from the help). This includes the `:!` command, so the following is enough:

```
nnoremap <C-q> :! %:p<CR>
```

Now, if you wanted to do more complex mangling than the `:p`, there would be two options:

- Using `:execute`: `nnoremap <C-q> :execute '!' expand('%:p')<CR>`
- Using `<C-R>` with the expression register: `nnoremap <C-q> :! <C-r>=expand('%:p')<CR><CR>`

Answer (score 2):

How about just using `%:p`

```
nnoremap <C-q> :!%:p<CR>
```